# IllegalStateException from SRTServletResponse (com.ibm:jaxws.thinclient 8.5) - websphere with spring and SSO configuration

Tags: spring, websphere, single-sign-on

during configuration SSO on websphere, I encountered strange issue. It does not interfere working of application (or I don't know about interference) but this error appears in logs

log:

```
 2019-12-06 14:18:03,754 ERROR DbLogEntryDao                  - com.somecompany.product.web.system.exception.BasicHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException (location: BasicHandlerExceptionResolver.java:65) Unexpected error at server SRPZZAPP0392.INSIM.BIZ: [java.lang.IllegalStateException [1575638283660] :null]
 2019-12-06 14:18:03,754 ERROR BasicHandlerExceptionResolver  - Unexpected error
 java.lang.IllegalStateException
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.addSessionCookie(SRTServletResponse.java:2177)
     at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionAffinityManager.setCookie(SessionAffinityManager.java:589)
     at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManager.adaptAndSetCookie(SessionManager.java:750)
     at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManager.createSession(SessionManager.java:737)
     at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.getIHttpSession(SessionContext.java:505)
     at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionContext.getIHttpSession(SessionContext.java:426)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTRequestContext.getSession(SRTRequestContext.java:113)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getSession(SRTServletRequest.java:2212)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getSession(SRTServletRequest.java:2196)
     at com.somecompany.product.web.utils.ContextHelper.getUserId(ContextHelper.java:178)
     at com.somecompany.product.web.utils.ContextHelper.getUser(ContextHelper.java:182)
     at com.somecompany.product.web.system.interceptors.SsoInterceptor.preHandle(SsoInterceptor.java:55)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:865)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
     at com.somecompany.product.web.spring.productDispatcherServlet.doService(productDispatcherServlet.java:28)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:551)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3496)
     at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.processSecurityPreInvokeException(CollaboratorHelper.java:145)
```

ContextHelper.getUserId(ContextHelper.java:178) code:

```
public static Long getUserId(HttpServletRequest request) {
 return (Long) request.getSession().getAttribute(SessionAttribute.USER);
}
```

did someone have to face similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `IllegalStateException` is thrown because `ContextHelper` asks for a session to be created, which ends up adding a Session cookie to the response after it has already been committed.

You can fix this by ensuring that a session is created before the response gets committed - eg. invoke `getSession()` earlier in your application's processing of the request.

Alternatively, this error can be avoided by replacing `getSession()` with `getSession(boolean create)` and passing false - which will prevent a session from being created if it doesn't already exist.  In the case of this error, however, a null `HttpSession` will be returned, so you'd need to further update your application logic to avoid `NullPointerExceptions`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)